# ActivityNotFoundException - activity has been declared in the manifest file

Tags: java, android

This is the place where the error is showing (`LoginActivity.java` file)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Login.class);    
startActivity(intent);    //showing error here
finish();
```

The login class I'm trying to call is under slideActivity and extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `LoginActivity` is a separate activity under separate package and extends `Activity`.

I have added `slideActivity` and `LoginActivity` to android manifest file. But the error is because of the `Login` class.

The error is shown below:

```
12969-12969/com.client.businesstracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.client.businesstracker/com.client.businesstracker.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1624)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
        at com.client.businesstracker.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:150)
        at com.client.businesstracker.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:120)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
```

here is my android manifest file

```
<activity     
        android:name=".SlideActivity"     
        android:label="@string/app_name" >     
        <intent-filter>     
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>     
    </activity>     
    <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"     
        android:label="@string/app_name" />     


<activity android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity" 
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Here is the Login.java file

```
package com.client.businesstracker;
import com.client.businesstracker.activity.LoginActivity;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;


public class Login extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtServerID;
private TextView txtClientID;
private Button btnLogout;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootview1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    txtName = (TextView) rootview1.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtServerID = (TextView) rootview1.findViewById(R.id.server_ID);
    txtClientID = (TextView) rootview1.findViewById(R.id.client_ID);
    btnLogout = (Button) rootview1.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String serverID = user.get("serverID");
    String clientID = user.get("clientID");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtServerID.setText(serverID);
    txtClientID.setText(clientID);


    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
    return rootview1;
}

/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 * */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

}

And here is the SlideActivity.java file from where I'm creating the object of the Login file as navigationDrawerItem

```
package com.client.businesstracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
//private ListView mDrawerList;
//private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide);
   // mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
   // addDrawerItems();
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment objFragment = null;
    Log.i("MyActivity", "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() — get item number " + position);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new Login();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new Connect();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new Home();
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new Preferences();
            break;
        case 4:
            objFragment = new AboutUs();
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slide, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((SlideActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

And here is the LoginActivity.java

```
package com.client.businesstracker.activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.client.businesstracker.Login;
import com.client.businesstracker.R;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.app.AppConfig;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.app.AppController;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.client.businesstracker.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputServerID;
private EditText inputClientID;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputServerID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverID);
    inputClientID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clientID);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String serverID = inputServerID.getText().toString().trim();
            String clientID = inputClientID.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!serverID.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !clientID.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(serverID, clientID,password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String serverID, final String clientID, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String serverID = user.getString("serverID");
                    String clientID = user.getString("clientID");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, serverID, clientID);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("serverID", serverID);
            params.put("clientID", clientID);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure that your Login class extends Activity or AppCompatActivity... and declare it inside Manifest file. However, I guess you want to start RegisterActivity from LoginActivity, so change to `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);   ` :)

Comment: I'm already extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment, so cannot extend Activity. And I don't need to call RegisterActivity.class but Login.class itself. Login is under navigationDrawer and extends fragment class

Comment: For fragment, you should read the following http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically you didn't defined the **Login.class** in **Manifest** file.

You have to add Login Activity in Manifest like below:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.Login"     
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Hiren...I tried that but it doesn't work. Its showing cannot resolve symbol Login in the manifest file.

Comment: @VarunJain, Have you created Login class ?

Comment: yes Hiren, I have uploaded the code to the Login class as well as other relevant files. Please have a look. Thanks..

Comment: @VarunJain, you have defined Login.java as Fragment, You can not start activity like this. You have two options: 1. Either change Login Fragment to Activity 2. or Replace Fragment by Fragment manager.

Comment: if i change the Login fragment to activity then I won't be able to call it from slideActivity and create it to the navigationDrawer. Can you suggest me some other alternatives such that I can keep the Login page to the navigationDrawer list. Thanks..

Comment: @VarunJain, First of all startActivity(this, SlideActivity.class) and after that call FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new Login())
            .commit();

Comment: Hi Hiren, can you provide insight as from where to call the FragmentManager. Really sorry for the trouble. This is my first android project and facing really tough time to get it done. Thanks for all the help anyways.

Comment: @VarunJain, You have to start parent activity of Fragment and then you have to replace fragment, Let me know if any clarification needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check exception first before thinking any thing else
com.client.businesstracker.Login
is not in your manifest

Comment: Hi Jotiram...I have tried it. Its saying **com.client.businesstracker.Login** is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'

Comment: could you send me your code i will check and replay